# How to refresh the React-Admin list data every X seconds?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

The [cache documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Caching.md) mentions that I can add a proxy to the dataprovider so that my responses are cached for X seconds, rather than React-Admin refreshing them on every page change. However, for my use case (a stock trading app), I'd like to get fresh data from my API for my listview every 1 second. I was expecting to do this by using the above cache method, but it looks like if the cache expires while the user is on a page, the page won't automatically refresh.

How can I get my React-Admin list view to refresh either every X seconds, or automatically on cache expiry?

Comment: Hello, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt. Please include specific details about what is or isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To periodically update the List View, you can use: `useRefresh()` from React-Admin and `useRecursiveTimeout()` from here:
https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-09-23-recursive-settimeout-with-react-hooks/

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { List, useRefresh } from 'react-admin';

function useRecursiveTimeout(callback, delay) { 
      const savedCallback = useRef(callback)

      useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback  
      }, [callback])

      useEffect(() => { 
        let id    
        function tick() {
          const ret = savedCallback.current()

          if (ret instanceof Promise) {
            ret.then(() => {
              if (delay !== null) {
                id = setTimeout(tick, delay)
              }
            })
          } else {
            if (delay !== null) {
              id = setTimeout(tick, delay)
            }
          }
        }
        if (delay !== null) {
          id = setTimeout(tick, delay)
          return () => id && clearTimeout(id)
        }
      }, [delay])
    }

    const MyList = (props) => {
      const refresh = useRefresh()
      useRecursiveTimeout(() => refresh(), 1000) 

      return (
        <List>
        ...
        </List>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With React Admin v.4+ List component uses [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery#_top) instead of Redux and you can pass queryOptions just like that

```
<List
  queryOptions={{ refetchInterval: 1000 }}
/>
```

Comment: This is awesome but can result in the deleted elements being deleted on the delete click, reappearing in the following refresh, only to be removed by the subsequent refresh. I am not sure why this happens but by putting it to 5 secs I was able to remove this. That is a bit flakey though...