# React-Admin - How to create a list view with autorefresh

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to create a list view with automatic reloading for example each 15 seconds.
Is it possible to make a list view with autorefresh feature in react admin framework?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61399283/how-to-refresh-the-react-admin-list-data-every-x-seconds/61407381#61407381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to the next solution:

```
const useAutoRefresh = function(url, interval){ 
    
    const refresh = useRefresh();

    useEffect(() => {           

        const timerAction = function(){         

            if(!document.hidden &&
              window.location.href.toLowerCase().endsWith(url.toLowerCase())){              
                refresh();
            }
        }

        setInterval(timerAction, interval); 
      }, []);   
}
```

and now we can use this function in our ListView

```
export const ProductCardList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} {...useAutoRefresh('/productcard', 5000)}>
```